# Using the same column name in MySQL and in HTML

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I am developing a PHP, MySQL application. I am following this principle where, I use the same column name in MySQL table as HTML variable name.

I found it to be really a good design technique:

1. I loop through the $_POST variable names, and update the table. Since the column name and the variable names are same, there are less chances of making an error while updating the database.

Is it a good practice to follow such a design technique ? I am not an expert, Does this expose our Database structure or something ?

I am also considering a variation to above design, where I append few strings used in HTML variables while creating the Database columns.

Comment: Well, it exposes your structure to someone who knows that that's what you're doing! But presumably you've adopted other best practices to secure your data.

Comment: I do the same thing, I don't think there is a problem with revealing your db column names but extreme care should be taken when writing the queries, make sure they're properly sanitized, unfortunately parameterized queries cant be used to filter column names

Comment: just make sure you whitelist your column names

Comment: An attacker could easily post an SQL injection as column name, so make sure you escape your column names and as @Ghost said.. Make a whitelist

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine for column names, and it is a good practice. I've used it successfully with both tables and views.

Others have pointed out something that's worth repeating: you need to secure your app against crackers.  If a badguy tries sending you a web request containing bogus column names, you definitely don't want your code passing them through. Trying to use column names from an untrusted source in requests to your database server is a big security risk, especially for INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs. You'll need to take some extra care with the part of your app that ensures column names are clean.

Something to watch out for: case sensitivity.  In MySQL you're in good shape for column-name case sensitivity.  But table name cases can change based on the OS in which your MySQL server runs. For best portability you should probably make your table names all lower case. Here's a writeup of that subject. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

If you port this project to Oracle you'll find yourself with case-sensitivity confusion in your column names.